# TextField Copies all Fields the same in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

When I type some text in one of the text fields, somehow it adds to all the text fields the same text at the same time. I am trying to separate them from each other so I can assign them correctly.

```
struct CardInfo : View {
    @State var creditCard : CreditCard
    @State var isSaved: Bool = false
    @State private(set) var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomTextField(data: $text, tFtext: "Kartin Uzerindeki Isim", tFImage: "user")
                .textContentType(.givenName)
                .onReceive(Just(text)) { data in
                    self.creditCard.cardOwnerName = self.text
            }
            CustomTextField(data: $text, tFtext: "Kredi Kart Numarasi", tFImage: "credit")
                .textContentType(.oneTimeCode)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                .onReceive(Just(text)) { data in 
                    self.creditCard.cardNumber = self.text
            }
```

```
struct CustomTextField: View {
    @Binding var data : String
    var tFtext: String = ""
    var tFImage: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
                Image(tFImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    .padding()
                TextField(tFtext, text: $data)
                    .padding()
                    .font(Font.custom("SFCompactDisplay", size: 16))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
            .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9647058824, green: 0.9725490196, blue: 0.9882352941, alpha: 1)))
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is because all text fields are using the same `@State` variable called `text`. If you type something in one text field, it will update the variable, and the variable will update the other text fields, because they rely on one and the same variable. pawello2222's answer contains the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use separate `@State` variables for each `TextField`:

```
struct CardInfo : View {
    @State var creditCard : CreditCard
    @State var isSaved: Bool = false
    @State private(set) var cardOwnerName = ""
    @State private(set) var cardNumber = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomTextField(data: $cardOwnerName, tFtext: "Kartin Uzerindeki Isim", tFImage: "user")
                .textContentType(.givenName)
                .onReceive(Just(cardOwnerName)) { data in
                    self.creditCard.cardOwnerName = data
            }
            CustomTextField(data: $cardNumber, tFtext: "Kredi Kart Numarasi", tFImage: "credit")
                .textContentType(.oneTimeCode)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                .onReceive(Just(cardNumber)) { data in 
                    self.creditCard.cardNumber = data
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```